# Create Related Terms Block Showing Terms on Taxonomy Term Page

Tags: views, 6, taxonomy-terms

Hi i have been hunting high and low for years to create this and i still havent found an answer. I have seen folks looking for similar but these questions usually went unanswered as if the answer is still unknown.

Im using views 2 and drupal 6. I am using the 'related terms' bit of when i edit a term. I would like to show the related terms to a term when viewing a taxonomy term page. I dont want to show nodes just terms.

I have created a term view and have played about with the Taxonomy: Related terms argument and Taxonomy: Related terms relationship but to no avail.

It sounds like quite a simple thing for drupal and views but for some reason there doesnt seem to be a definate answer to this. all help appreciated. thaks

Answer (score 2):

First off, I wanted to let you know that this is not necessarily intuitive, and there's very hacked methods of doing this. Another thing that I want to mention is that I did this in Drupal 7 with Views 3. However, one of the things that I *think* is most different is the UI. So text descriptions should be able to guide you. :)

The way that I went about doing this is as follows:

In Views, I created a block which is to display the content type of the related items (mine was recipes). I added the fields which I wanted to appear, which were just pictures and titles. Then in Contextual Filters (I think D6/Views2 calls this arguments), I added two.

The first is "Content: Nid" and I configured it as follows:
When filter value is not available => Provide default value => Type: Content ID from URL. Under "more" (not sure what V2 calls it), there's an option called "exclude", which if selected, the numbers entered for the filter will be excluded rather than limiting the view. This is great because it essentially says, "Return me the list of everything of this content type EXCEPT this one that I'm on."

The second filter is "Content: Has taxonomy term ID". This one was a bit trivial because I want to provide relationships on multiple vocabularies of taxonomy terms. So it's configured as follows: When the filter value is NOT available => Provide Default Value => Taxonomy term ID from URL => Load default filter from **node** page => Limit terms by vocabulary => Selected my vocabularies => Multiple-value handling -> filter to items that share any term.

When the filter value IS available or a default is provided => Specify validation criteria => Validator = Taxonomy term, with my previous chosen vocabularies selected again => Filter value type => Term IDs separated by , o + . Under "more", I checked "allow multiple filter values to work together."

This was the way that I was able to get the related content. I specified the amount of results that I wanted in the pager.

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Thanks prof. Nice description there. I think you are listing nodes though and i want to list related terms. Everywhere it seems folks want to make up related node lists but nowhere seems to want to know about related tags. I accidentally managed to display a related tag once but it was only a one way relationship.